# Open cassandra connection only once in Django

Tags: python, django, session, cassandra

I want to open only one single connection to my cassandra database in Django.
I did not find anything on this topic unfortunately.

At the moment I got a class which i iniate whenever I need to query:

```
class CassConnection():

    def __init__(self):
        self.auth_prov = PlainTextAuthProvider(settings.runtime_settings[k.CASSANDRA_USER],
                                               settings.runtime_settings[k.CASSANDRA_PASSWORD])
        self.cluster = Cluster(settings.runtime_settings[k.CASSANDRA_CLUSTER], auth_provider=self.auth_prov)
        self.session = self.cluster.connect(keyspace=settings.runtime_settings[k.KEYSPACE_TIREREADINGS])
        self.session.row_factory = dict_factory

    def get_session(self):
        return self.session
```

I open a new Session in other classes for every query I make by:

```
    self.con = CassConnection()
    self.session = self.con.get_session()
```

Anyone a hint, how to keep the session open and make it accesible via multiple packages?

Comment: "I want to open only one single connection" : one connection per request ? one connection per process ? one connection per thread ?

Comment: One connection as long as the backend is not restarted completely. So per django process.

Answer (score 1):

For a "one connection per Django process" scheme, basically, what you want is

- a connection proxy class (which you already have) with a "lazy" connection behaviour (doesn't connect until someone tries to use the connection),
- a module-global instance of this class that other packages can import, and
- a way to ensure the connection gets properly closed (which [cassandra requires](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cluster.html#cassandra.cluster.Cluster.shutdown) for proper operation)

This last point well be the main difficulty as none of the available options (mainly `atexit.register()` and the `__del__(self)` method) are 101% reliable. Implementing `__del__(self)` on your connection proxy might be the most reliable still, just beware of circular depencies (http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/06/12/safely-using-destructors-in-python might be a good read here).

Also note that a "one single connection per django process" mean your connections must be totally thread-safe, as you usually will have many threads per Django process (depending on your wsgi container configuration).

Another solution - if thread-safety is an issue - might be to have a single connection per request...